# Why does R interpreter segfault on an underscore?

Tags: r

This is more out of curiosity than anything else, but why does an `_` cause the R interpreter to segfault? More generally, is there a list somewhere of input characters that will cause the R interpreter to die?

When the following script is sourced, it causes the R interpreter to segfault.

```
for  (_ in 1:50) {
}
```

This is reproducible by running `R` on the command line and then typing

```
source("Foo.r")
```

I am running 3.0.2. I am curious because it took me some time to isolate this bug.

Comment: I get an error, but no segfault.

Comment: Did you run it using "source"?

Comment: Ok, sourcing segfaults for me.

Comment: error but no segfault for me even when sourcing (`R Under development (unstable) (2013-11-28 r64348) Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)`)

Comment: This should be reported to r-devel: r-devel@r-project.org   Please include more specifics about OS. You should expect the to be delayed while awaiting moderator review if you are not subscribed. (One might argue that it should be sent to the Bugs list, since it is reproducible on two separate systems and segfaults are bugs by definition, but the R-Core generally prefer submission to r-devel.)

Comment: I should clarify that I tried that in RStudio, and RStudio told me that my R session aborted and restarted the session. I assume that was a segfault.

Comment: In R.app on a Mac I get a segfault with: `source(textConnection("for  (_ in 1:50) { }") )` and get one as well when doing that in a Terminal session, both with R 3.0.2.

Comment: segfault on MacOS for me too (R.app v 3.0.2)

Comment: So who wants to write up the bug report?

Comment: There is no segfault for me when sourcing. `R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
`

Comment: As you prob. know (but should include in bug report), it's ok to name an object `x_`  but not `_x` .

Comment: error but no segfault when sourcing. `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)` (This is running on under Windows 7).

Answer (score 7):

This is a [known bug in R 3.0.2](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15518) that has already been fixed and will be available in the next release, as documented in the [read me file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/NEWS) for the latest patched sources. The R development team determined that this bug is not OS-specific and that it only affects R 3.0.2.

Read the bug report above and the source code for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but more test data:

OSX 3.0.2,  if I do <\cmd>E on a text file,

```
Rgames> source("/var/folders/+N/+NUwiD8-Fse2oprSglHTd++++TM/-Tmp-//RtmphWNc9F/file17f8f461ba1ed")
Error in source("/var/folders/+N/+NUwiD8-Fse2oprSglHTd++++TM/-Tmp-//RtmphWNc9F/file17f8f461ba1ed") : 
  /var/folders/+N/+NUwiD8-Fse2oprSglHTd++++TM/-Tmp-//RtmphWNc9F/file17f8f461ba1ed:1:7: unexpected input
1: for  (_
         ^
Rgames> unlink("/var/folders/+N/+NUwiD8-Fse2oprSglHTd++++TM/-Tmp-
//RtmphWNc9F/file17f8f461ba1ed")
```

Similarly, if I save the text file,

```
Rgames> source('foo.r')
Error in source("foo.r") : foo.r:1:7: unexpected input
1: for  (_
         ^
```

So this clearly is not a bug on all operating systems.
Further, I tried doing  "source(textConnection("for (_ in 1:50) { }") )" like DWin posted in comments, and got no segfault in R.app GUI.

ETA: No segfault under Win7x64, R3.0.2x64, either from cygwin command line or rgui.exe.

Comment: same for me (`R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`). And this error seams resonable to me...

Comment: So next question:  which of you are NOT using 64-bit R on OSX, or other operating systems?